# Я хочу отображать на экране файлы, которые были созданы time или менее минут назад, и папки их содержащие.

Tags: java, android

В эмуляторе все работает как надо, однако на реальных устройствах появляется куча давно созданных файлов. Не подскажете, почему так происходит?

```
private void fill(File f)
{
    File[]dirs = f.listFiles(); 
     this.setTitle("Current Dir: "+f.getName());
     List<Item>dir = new ArrayList<Item>();
     List<Item>fls = new ArrayList<Item>();
     try{
         for(File ff: dirs)
         { 
            Date lastModDate = new Date(ff.lastModified());


             final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
             int time = Integer.parseInt(Time1);
             c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, - time);

             SimpleDateFormat dfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
             String currentDate = dfDate.format(c.getTime());
             String Date = dfDate.format(lastModDate);

            if(ff.isDirectory()){


                File[] fbuf = ff.listFiles();
                int buf = 0;
                if(fbuf != null){
                    buf = fbuf.length;
                }
                else buf = 0;
                String num_item = String.valueOf(buf);
                if(buf == 0) num_item = num_item + " item";
                else num_item = num_item + " items";
                if (CheckDates(Date, currentDate)) {
                    dir.add(new Item(ff.getName(), num_item, Date, ff.getAbsolutePath(), "directory_icon", Uri.fromFile(ff)));

                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (CheckDates(Date, currentDate)) {
                    String name = ff.getName();
                    String image;
                    String extension = ff.getAbsolutePath().substring(ff.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("."));
                    if (extension.equals(".jpg")  || extension.equals(".png")  || extension.equals(".jpeg"))  image = "file_image";
                    else if (extension.equals(".pdf")) image = "file_pdf";
                        else if (extension.equals(".pptx")) image = "file_powerpoint";
                            else image = "file";


                    fls.add(new Item(name , getSize(ff), Date, ff.getAbsolutePath(), image, Uri.fromFile(ff)));
                }

            }
         }
     }catch(Exception e)
     {    

     }
     Collections.sort(dir);
     Collections.sort(fls);
     dir.addAll(fls);
     if(!f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard"))
         dir.add(0,new Item("...","Parent Directory","",f.getParent(),"arrow", Uri.fromFile(f)));
     adapter = new FileArrayAdapter(FileChooser.this,R.layout.file_view,dir);
     this.setListAdapter(adapter); 
}
private static boolean CheckDates(String startDate, String endDate) {

    if (startDate.compareTo(endDate)>0) {return true;}
    else {return false;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сравнение дат через `compareTo` их строк некорректно. Используйте `Date.compareTo`/`Date.after`/`Date.before`, например:

```
private static boolean checkDates(Date date1, Date date2) {
    return date1.after(date2);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, только почему использованное мною сравнение дат работало в эмуляторе?

Comment: @AlexKhamitov, ну, в некоторых частных случаях сравнение дат через строки, возможно и будет работать) но в целом это неверно